# How to fill in a form field inside a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm looking for a way to fill a field inside a Jinja2 template, but when I do the assignment to prepopulate it as I would do in python I get the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '.'

Here's the code line:

```
{% set form.nombre.data = categoria.nombre %}
{{ form.nombre }}
```

What would be the right way to do it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why you need do it in template? Mb set field in form itself or pass initial to form in view.

Comment: I think exception not coming from this piece of template. It's likely you miss a `{% endblock %}` instruction

Comment: Because the logic of making the field as a form or not, I have it inside the template, so I would like it to be inside it. I had already thought to do it outside if I did not find the way =(

The exception comes by "form.name.data" apparently the dots "." make the exception occur